# can i find the algorithim of a prng by entering previous sequence

Tags: random-number-generator

Is there any software or can i find it manually the algorithm of a prng by entering previous sequences of results. there is 38 possible outcomes and results can repeat.

Comment: Depending on what the algorithm is, it can be anywhere between trivial and impossible.

Comment: Thanks - so if i have a large sequence of results what is the best way to see patterns  and the most likely results that are coming

Comment: I'd try looking for correlations between symbols, such as "if I see symbol A, what's the distribution of symbols following or prior to that", or "if a look at the difference of adjacent symbols, is that equidistributed?".  If you have the time, you might investigate pairs N symbols away, or triplets, etc.  Any such nontrivial correlation you find is a big hint to what the PRNG might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the PRNG is a cryptographically secure PRNG, then no. A [basic property of CSPRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator#Requirements) is that if you know all the bits of a sequence of outputs except one, then your probability of guessing that one bit is no better than pure chance.

A deterministic CSPRNG operates by having a secret state. Without finding out the secret state, there's no way to guess outputs.

If the PRNG is not cryptographically secure, then it might be possible to reconstruct some outputs knowing others. In fact that possibility is basically the definition of not being cryptographically secure. Realistically, unless the PRNG is extremely bad, it's rather difficult to find the algorithm given only a few outputs, but it might be very easy to find if you manage to guess the algorithm. Maybe it's a [common one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators)?